# Invoke Spotify ad in premium version

Tags: spotify

For testing my app (Spotify Apps API) for the free version of Spotify I need to invoke a commercial track. In the following document it says that I can use the URI spotify:ad:9ca1a889f34945d59fc521759dd177a7   to invoke the commercial program: http://d2mua6lfj9ozyq.cloudfront.net/old/pdf/partner-checklist.pdf I also remember that this used to work in the past, but when I type in the search bar now, there is simply nothing happening, nor there is any error message. What can I do to invoke a commercial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an alternative ad URI, like spotify:ad:5e8c1e01cc7d4e16a0c273ecd93d2742